# ns-3：Discrepancy in Timestamps in mysecond.cc Example Output

Tags: networking, ns-3

I've been learning ns-3 using the official tutorial and encountered an issue while studying the mysecond.cc example. There is a slight discrepancy in the timestamps between my output and the one presented in the tutorial, even though I'm using the identical code provided.

For example, the log in the official tutorial reads:

```
"At time +2.0078s server received 1024 bytes from 10.1.1.1 port 49153."
```

However, my output reads:

```
"At time +2.0118s server received 1024 bytes from 10.1.1.1 port 49153."
```

This difference persists even when examining the second-2-0.pcap. I've attached the screenshots from the official tutorial and my output for comparison.
official:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HmfB.png)
my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LliA2.png)
Initially, I thought this could be due to variations in the operating environments, so I ran the simulation on both a virtual machine (VMWare Ubuntu) and WSL2. However, the outputs were identical in both cases. I also considered the possibility of a version mismatch in ns-3, and tested the simulation using both ns3.37 and ns3.38. The issue remained the same.

I've thoroughly reviewed my setup and the ns-3 versions, and I can't seem to identify any deviations from the official tutorial.

My setup details are as follows:

NS-3 version: ns3.37 and ns3.38
Operating system: WSL2 and VMWare Ubuntu
You can find the code I used below:

```
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"

#include "ns3/core-module.h"

#include "ns3/csma-module.h"

#include "ns3/internet-module.h"

#include "ns3/ipv4-global-routing-helper.h"

#include "ns3/network-module.h"

#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"

#include "ns3/netanim-module.h"

// Default Network Topology

//

//       10.1.1.0

// n0 -------------- n1   n2   n3   n4

//    point-to-point  |    |    |    |

//                    ================

//                      LAN 10.1.2.0

 

using namespace ns3;

NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE("SecondScriptExample");

int

main(int argc, char* argv[])

{

    std::string animFile = "animation_mysecond.xml";

    bool verbose = true;

    uint32_t nCsma = 3;

 

    CommandLine cmd(__FILE__);

    cmd.AddValue("nCsma", "Number of \"extra\" CSMA nodes/devices", nCsma);

    cmd.AddValue("verbose", "Tell echo applications to log if true", verbose);

 

    cmd.Parse(argc, argv);

 

    if (verbose)

    {

        LogComponentEnable("UdpEchoClientApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);

        LogComponentEnable("UdpEchoServerApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);

    }

 

    nCsma = nCsma == 0 ? 1 : nCsma;

 

    NodeContainer p2pNodes;

    p2pNodes.Create(2);

 

    NodeContainer csmaNodes;

    csmaNodes.Add(p2pNodes.Get(1));

    csmaNodes.Create(nCsma);

 

    PointToPointHelper pointToPoint;

    pointToPoint.SetDeviceAttribute("DataRate", StringValue("5Mbps"));

    pointToPoint.SetChannelAttribute("Delay", StringValue("2ms"));

 

    NetDeviceContainer p2pDevices;

    p2pDevices = pointToPoint.Install(p2pNodes);

 

    CsmaHelper csma;

    csma.SetChannelAttribute("DataRate", StringValue("100Mbps"));

    csma.SetChannelAttribute("Delay", TimeValue(NanoSeconds(6560)));

 

    NetDeviceContainer csmaDevices;

    csmaDevices = csma.Install(csmaNodes);

 

    InternetStackHelper stack;

    stack.Install(p2pNodes.Get(0));

    stack.Install(csmaNodes);

 

    Ipv4AddressHelper address;

    address.SetBase("10.1.1.0", "255.255.255.0");

    Ipv4InterfaceContainer p2pInterfaces;

    p2pInterfaces = address.Assign(p2pDevices);

 

    address.SetBase("10.1.2.0", "255.255.255.0");

    Ipv4InterfaceContainer csmaInterfaces;

    csmaInterfaces = address.Assign(csmaDevices);

 

    UdpEchoServerHelper echoServer(9);

 

    ApplicationContainer serverApps = echoServer.Install(csmaNodes.Get(nCsma));

    serverApps.Start(Seconds(1.0));

    serverApps.Stop(Seconds(10.0));

 

    UdpEchoClientHelper echoClient(csmaInterfaces.GetAddress(nCsma), 9);

    echoClient.SetAttribute("MaxPackets", UintegerValue(1));

    echoClient.SetAttribute("Interval", TimeValue(Seconds(1.0)));

    echoClient.SetAttribute("PacketSize", UintegerValue(1024));

 

    ApplicationContainer clientApps = echoClient.Install(p2pNodes.Get(0));

    clientApps.Start(Seconds(2.0));

    clientApps.Stop(Seconds(10.0));

 

    Ipv4GlobalRoutingHelper::PopulateRoutingTables();

 

    pointToPoint.EnablePcapAll("second");

    csma.EnablePcap("second", csmaDevices.Get(1), true);

  

      AnimationInterface anim(animFile);

       anim.EnablePacketMetadata();

        anim.EnableIpv4L3ProtocolCounters(Seconds(0), Seconds(10));

    anim.SetConstantPosition (p2pNodes.Get (0), 10.0, 10.0);

    anim.SetConstantPosition (p2pNodes.Get (1), 30.0, 30.0);

    for (uint32_t i = 1; i < nCsma+1; i=i+1)

    {

        anim.SetConstantPosition (csmaNodes.Get (i), 50.0, 50.0 + i * 20);

    }

    std::cout << "nCsma: " << nCsma << std::endl;  // 打印 nCsma 的值

 

    Simulator::Run();

    Simulator::Destroy();

    return 0;


}
```

I'm puzzled about why this discrepancy exists and what might be causing it. has anyone  experienced a similar issue or has any insights into what might be happening?

I followed the official ns-3 tutorial and tried to run the provided mysecond.cc example without any modifications to the code. I expected to reproduce the same results that are shown in the tutorial, including identical timestamps in the logs.

However, when I ran the simulation and examined the output logs, I noticed a slight discrepancy in the timestamps. For example, when the server received a packet of 1024 bytes, the time reported in my output was consistently 0.004 seconds later than that reported in the official example. I observed this discrepancy in the second-2-0.pcap file as well.

I attempted to troubleshoot this by running the simulation in two different environments: a VMWare Ubuntu virtual machine and WSL2. Unfortunately, both environments produced the same discrepancy in timestamps. I also tested the simulation using two different ns-3 versions (ns3.37 and ns3.38), but the discrepancy persisted.

Despite my efforts, I have not been able to identify the source of this discrepancy or find a way to produce output that matches the official tutorial. I'm seeking help in understanding why this discrepancy is occurring and how I can correct it.